# how can I adapt a bootstrap carousel to contain a form while remaining responsive (code example inside)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have modified a carousel to contain a form and i'm having trouble getting things laid out the way I want in the grid.
[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4jH3TEqM6M)
If you load this on a computer the layout is looking the way i want, however when the browser is set to the breakpoints of small and xs.
The mobile look i am trying to achieve is

```
A D D R E S S
U n i t
Submit
```

The Destop should look like this should you be viewing from a mobile:

```
A d d r e s s Unit S u b m i t
```

where unit field is a significantly smaller in width than address or the submit button
I had attempted to use col-xs-push-2 and I was able to get it how i wanted but i was never able to get it to pull back with col-md-pull-x.